# CSS files defined in .info file are being ignored

Tags: 7, theming

Having followed a number of different guides to try and create a Bartik sub theme that allowed me to use the Color module, the following was the last one I attempted that worked: http://drupal.org/node/800510#comment-3277090

However despite this working, none of the CSS files specified in my sub theme are working. Following is my info file:

```
; $Id: bartik.info,v 1.5 2010/11/07 00:27:20 dries Exp $

name = crxtr
description = A bartik sub theme
core = 7.x
base theme = bartik

stylesheets[all][] = css/crxtr.css
stylesheets[all][] = css/colors.css
stylesheets[all][] = css/crxtr-views.css

regions[header] = Header
regions[help] = Help
regions[page_top] = Page top
regions[page_bottom] = Page bottom
regions[highlighted] = Highlighted

regions[featured] = Featured
regions[content] = Content
regions[sidebar_first] = Sidebar first
regions[sidebar_second] = Sidebar second

regions[triptych_first] = Triptych first
regions[triptych_middle] = Triptych middle
regions[triptych_last] = Triptych last

regions[footer_firstcolumn] = Footer first column
regions[footer_secondcolumn] = Footer second column
regions[footer_thirdcolumn] = Footer third column
regions[footer_fourthcolumn] = Footer fourth column
regions[footer] = Footer

settings[shortcut_module_link] = 0

; Information added by drupal.org packaging script on 2011-01-05
version = "7.0"
project = "drupal"
datestamp = "1294208756"
```

Now the CSS from my front page reads:

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("http://local.tracker/modules/system/system.base.css?ll8uzr");
@import url("http://local.tracker/modules/system/system.menus.css?ll8uzr");
@import url("http://local.tracker/modules/system/system.messages.css?ll8uzr");
@import url("http://local.tracker/modules/system/system.theme.css?ll8uzr");</style> 
<style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("http://local.tracker/misc/ui/jquery.ui.core.css?ll8uzr");
@import url("http://local.tracker/misc/ui/jquery.ui.theme.css?ll8uzr");
@import url("http://local.tracker/modules/overlay/overlay-parent.css?ll8uzr");
@import url("http://local.tracker/modules/contextual/contextual.css?ll8uzr");</style> 
<style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("http://local.tracker/modules/comment/comment.css?ll8uzr");
@import url("http://local.tracker/modules/field/theme/field.css?ll8uzr");
@import url("http://local.tracker/modules/node/node.css?ll8uzr");
@import url("http://local.tracker/modules/search/search.css?ll8uzr");
@import url("http://local.tracker/modules/user/user.css?ll8uzr");
@import url("http://local.tracker/sites/all/modules/views/css/views.css?ll8uzr");</style> 
<style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("http://local.tracker/sites/all/modules/ctools/css/ctools.css?ll8uzr");
@import url("http://local.tracker/modules/shortcut/shortcut.css?ll8uzr");
@import url("http://local.tracker/modules/toolbar/toolbar.css?ll8uzr");</style> 
<style type="text/css" media="all">@import url("http://local.tracker/themes/bartik/css/layout.css?ll8uzr");
@import url("http://local.tracker/themes/bartik/css/style.css?ll8uzr");
@import url("http://local.tracker/sites/default/files/color/crxtr-5fa2c1e5/colors.css?ll8uzr");</style> 
<style type="text/css" media="print">@import url("http://local.tracker/themes/bartik/css/print.css?ll8uzr");</style>
```

The 3 CSS files specified in the info file are present and contain rules.

Following is an excerpt also from the head, which shows that at least on some level, the info file is being parsed and the CSS files are being recognized:

```
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--...,"sites\/all\/themes\/crxtr\/css\/colors.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/crxtr\/css\/crxtr.css":1,"sites\/all\/themes\/crxtr\/css\/crxtr-views.css":1,...//--><!]]>
```

I've tried clearing the cache about a billion times to no effect. I just tried adding the following line to my info file and corresponding CSS file, and the only effect was that it actually removed the bartik/css/style.css from the HEAD, rather than substituting or adding the crxtr/css/style.css:

```
stylesheets[all][] = css/style.css
```

Please let me know if I can provide any more info to diagnose.

Edit: Followed the same process to create a subtheme using NineSixty and have had no problems with it finding and loading my sub-theme CSS files.

Answer (score 2):

Please rename your css file name style.css to blah.css, it will works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Drupal 7, and those days I also had problems subtheming Bartik myself or copying and modifying the whole Bartik folder into my themes folder. At the end, I did using the only 'official' Bartik sub-theme I found ([Antonelli](http://drupal.org/project/antonelli)) and then changing CSS and stuff in the info of Antonelli instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Did you need to do anything special to get theme preprocess hooks working?

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to point out that it appears Drupal is quite particular about the location *and/or* name of your css file when including it via a module's **.info** file. This is what worked for me:

**Directory**

```
sites/all/modules/custom/my_module/
```

**Files**

```
my_module.info
my_module.module
css/my_module.css // DOES NOT WORK
css/foo.css
```

**my_module.info**

```
name = My Module
description = My awesome module
core = 7.x
package = Other
stylesheets[all][] = css/my_module.css // DOES NOT WORK
stylesheets[all][] = css/foo.css
```

For some *reason*, **.css** files included via a module's **.info** file, *cannot have the same filename* as the module itself. This means the **my_module.css** file will *not* be loaded.

Be sure to *flush all of Drupal's caches* after making changes to a **.info** file.